# PHP failed to insert and retrieve data from database

Tags: php, html, database, date, sqlsrv

I'm trying to have it so when the user inputs their first name, surname and current location, The Date/Time should automatically be inputted (logged) into the Date column and saved. It should then display all rows in a table. I keep getting an error (below).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 

<head> 
<title></title> 
</head>

<center>
    <h2> ACW LOCATION TRACOR </h2>
</center>

<body>
    <table width="200" border="5" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
            <th> Username </th>
            <th> First_Name </th>
            <th> Surname </th>
            <th> Current_Location </th>
            <th> TimeStamp </th>
        <tr>

<?php
$server = 'SQL2008.net.dcs.hull.ac.uk';

$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"rde_531545");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server,$connectionInfo);
$query='create table Location ';
$query .= '(Username int NOT NULL IDENTITY(500, 23), First_Name varchar(50) NOT NULL, Surname varchar(50) NOT NULL, Current_Location varchar(50) NOT NULL, Date Datetime NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (Username))';
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);

if (!$result){
 if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null){
    foreach( $errors as $error ){
        echo "<p>Error: ".$error[ 'message']."</p>";
        }
    }
}
else{
    echo "<p>DB successfully created</p>";
    }
sqlsrv_close($conn);

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$Date =  new DateTime();
$DateStr = $Date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$server = 'SQL2008.net.dcs.hull.ac.uk'; 
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"rde_531545"); 
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server,$connectionInfo); 
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO Location (First_Name, Surname, Current_Location, Date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"; 
$params = array("Jon","Doey","Leeds", $DateStr); 
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$insert_query,$params);
$params = array("John","Doe","Hull", $DateStr);
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$insert_query,$params);

$SelectQuery='SELECT Username, First_Name, Surname, Current_Location, Date FROM Location'; 
$results = sqlsrv_query($conn, $SelectQuery); 

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['Username']."</td><td>".$row['First_Name']."</td><td>".$row['Surname']."</td><td>".$row['Current_Location']."</td><td>".$dateStr = $Date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")."</td></tr>";
} 

sqlsrv_close($conn);

?>

    </table>
</body> 
</html>
```

Desired Output:

> 512| Jane | Doe | Hull | 2012/12/12 18:24:45PM

I keep getting this error also it doesn't save the date to the database:

> **Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in C:\RDEUsers\NET\531545\LocationPOST.php on line 69**

Comment: just concatenate `$DateStr`, no need for another declaration

Comment: Ghost how do I go about doing that?

Comment: @Accœnt Where is this **line 69** pointing at?

Comment: @Ghost & Bluetree Thanks guys that got rid of the error, however, is there no way of having it so each entry insert into the database it will also add the date/time and save it. Then the next time I look at that entry it will show that date as currently it only shows the current date when I refresh the page, instead of the date/time when I added the entry.

Comment: If you want to save the current date/time in database when you insert. you can just set the default of `Date` column to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` . If you want to update your `Date` Column into a current date when you refresh your page then you can just use UPDATE statement.

Comment: Change `Date Datetime NOT NULL` to `varchar(40) Datetime NOT NULL`